# Вернуть значение стиля

Tags: css, input, checkbox

После включения чекбокса меняется значение стиля для указанного блока div. 
Значение устанавливается `left:0;` и `width: 245px;`

```css
#on:checked ~ .div {
  left:0;
  width: 245px;
}
    
.div {
  position: fixed;
  left:-245px;
}
```

```html
<input id="on" type="checkbox">
<label for="on">Клацать</label>

<div class="div">текст</div>
```

Чудеса в том, что после перезагрузки страницы значение CSS для блока `div` не возвращается к `left:-245px;`

Как вернуть значение для класса `div` после перезагрузки страницы в браузере Firefox?

Comment: Это какая-то ерунда в браузере. Он не обновляет страницу

Comment: Вопрос обновил/уточнил.

Comment: Я сам в шоке, от этого чуда.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать эту же функцию с помощью JS. Там должно работать правильно. Это просто Firefox не снимает флажок с input при обновлении страницы

Comment: Я пытаюсь избавится от JS таким способом.

Comment: Добавьте в js, что бы при загрузке страницы он снимал флажок ) Но это уже костыль

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось довольно простым. На W3C есть пример как отключить автоматически устанавливать галочку для элемента input.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute

```
<input id="on" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
```